# Reproduce "enter" button MATLAB

Tags: matlab, input, user-input, enter

I have a long code to run some numerical simulations. It interacts with the user. However, since it could take a very long time, I am working on "automating" it by setting some defaults options (in case one runs it overnight).

At a certain point I have:

```
answ = input([newline 'Do you want to plot side-by-side PSDs of MODAL RESPONSE?' newline...
   'If YES, please select which mode:    ''overlapped''(o)/''not overlapped''(no) :     '], 's');
```

I would like to code that if more than 10s passes without any action, the default option (o) is passed, such that answ='o'.

I tried with "timer" MATLAB function like:

```
tim = timer('TimerFcn', 'stat=false; disp(''o''), return', 'startdelay', 10);
```

however, I am missing the step of "reproducing" the ENTER press from the keyboard, such to assign 'o' to answ.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119067-how-can-i-set-a-time-for-input-waiting#answer_318457

Comment: Or you could keep is simple and remove the user interaction altogether. Just comment out that line and add `answ='o';`.